# Creating a php class for database insert functions

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create a class to save time on cleaning up my variables before sending them to the database to prevent sql injections. The basic systems is working now but i cant seem to get a where/or statement implemented. Does anyone know how to add this?

```
<?php

class Database {
    private $db = '';
    private $database = '';

    function __construct($settings) {
        $this->db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', $settings['mysql_user']['username'], $settings['mysql_user']['password']);
        $this->database = $settings['mysql_user']['database'];

        print_r('Database Loaded!<br/>');
    }
    public function query($method, $database, $rows, $params, $where = array(), $or = array()) {
        $count = 0;
        $amount = count($rows);
        $final_rows = '';
        $final_data = '';
        $bind_names = array();
        $bind_names[0] = '';
        $param_types = array(
            "int" => "i",
            "string" => "s",
            "double" => "d",
            "blob" => "b"
        );

        switch($method) {
            case 'INSERT':
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    $count = $count + 1;
                    $final_rows .= '`' . $row . '`' . ($count != $amount ? ', ' : '');
                    $final_data .= '?' . ($count != $amount ? ', ' : '');
                }

                $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO `' . $this->database . '`.`' . $database . '` (' . $final_rows . ') VALUES (' . $final_data . ')');

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i++)
                {
                   $bind_name = 'bind'.$i;
                   $$bind_name = $params[$i][1];
                   $bind_names[0] .= $param_types[$params[$i][0]];
                   $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;
                }

                call_user_func_array( array ($stmt, 'bind_param'), $bind_names); 

                return $stmt->execute();
            break;
            case 'UPDATE':
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    $count = $count + 1;
                    $final_rows .= '`' . $row . '`' . ($count != $amount ? ', ' : '');
                    $final_data .= '?' . ($count != $amount ? ', ' : '');
                }

                $stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE `' . $this->database . '`.`' . $database . '` SET ' . $final_rows . '');

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i++)
                {
                   $bind_name = 'bind'.$i;
                   $$bind_name = $params[$i][1];
                   $bind_names[0] .= $param_types[$params[$i][0]];
                   $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;
                }

                call_user_func_array( array ($stmt, 'bind_param'), $bind_names); 

                return $stmt->execute();
            break;
            case 'REPLACE':
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    $count = $count + 1;
                    $final_rows .= '`' . $row . '`' . ($count != $amount ? ', ' : '');
                    $final_data .= '?' . ($count != $amount ? ', ' : '');
                }

                $stmt = $this->db->prepare('REPLACE INTO `' . $this->database . '`.`' . $database . '` (' . $final_rows . ') VALUES (' . $final_data . ')');

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i++)
                {
                   $bind_name = 'bind'.$i;
                   $$bind_name = $params[$i][1];
                   $bind_names[0] .= $param_types[$params[$i][0]];
                   $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;
                }

                call_user_func_array( array ($stmt, 'bind_param'), $bind_names); 

                return $stmt->execute();
            break;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: This is a bit board... I wouldn't go for a big big "query" method, but split it in several methods : `select()`, `from()`, `join()`, `leftJoin()`, `where()`, ... and kipping a `query` attribute to build it. You have an example [here](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class) of a class you could end up with.

Comment: I prefer this way becouse its easy to add or remove things later and so I only have to change the `$method` variable for a different type of query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to make a few assumptions, but first I'll recommend you use an ORM before whipping up your own solution. Here's a good list of PHP libraries (I've linked to the database sections, which includes some very well done stand-alone ORMs https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php#database)

That being said I'm going to assume the $where and $or arrays are both for the WHERE construct and the items in $where are combined via AND and the $or is combined via OR.

Because you didn't describe what kind of output you were looking for I'm also assuming your $where and $or are key/value pairs which translates to "key=value AND key=value AND (key=value OR key=value)".

DISCLAIMER: This example is kind of hacky, but is the shortest/simplest way to get the example across.

```
$whereQuery = '';
foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
    $whereQuery .= "$key = $value AND";
}

if ($or !== array()) {
    $whereQuery .= '(';
    foreach ($or as $key => $value) {
        $whereQuery .= "$key = $value OR";
    }
}

if ($whereQuery !== '') {
    if (($temp = strlen($whereQuery) - strlen('AND')) >= 0 && strpos($whereQuery, 'AND', $temp) !== false) {
         $whereQuery = substr($whereQuery, -4);
    } else {
         $whereQuery = substr($whereQuery, -3) . ')';
    }
    $whereQuery = "WHERE $whereQuery";
}
```

You can then stick the $whereQuery at the end of an UPDATE or SELECT. Even if $where and $or are empty it'll still work.

You could move the loops into functions and make it recursive if the $value was another array so you could create more complex WHERE statements.